# If statement for an element appearing twice in a list in Python

Tags: python

In Python, I have two lists of coordinates like [(2,4),(4,5)]. One is filled with 10 coordinates and the other is empty. I have the code set out so if the coordinate the player inputs is the array. It will append the coordinate to the empty array which will represent the 'visited' coordinates. I want an if statement that will check if the element of 'coordinate' appears in the 'visits' list twice.

```
def corcheck(coordinate,+10locations,+10visits,losecoinslocations,coins):
    if coordinate in +10locations:
        coins=coins+10
        coordinate.append(+10visits)
        print("+10")
#        if coordinate in
    elif coordinate in losecoinslocations:
        coins=0
        print("You lose all your coins. -",coins)
    else:
        print("This square was empty. Please make your next move.")
    return +10visits,+10num,losecoinsnum,coins
```

The line which is editied with #is where the check will be placed for if the coordinate element appears in +10 visits twice, from there it will be appended to losecoinslocations.

Comment: `if coordinate in +10locations:` is invalid syntax!

Comment: `10locations` and `10visits` aren't valid python identifiers ...

Comment: can't find a duplicate of this, it's too basic...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if all elements in a list are unique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278122/checking-if-all-elements-in-a-list-are-unique)

Comment: Please clarify the problem: do you need to know whether there exists any duplicated element, or which elements are duplicated?  If an element appears 3 or 4 times, do you need that quantity?

Answer (score 1):

```
if len(coordinate ) != len(set(coordinate )):
```

set  removes duplicates , and check the lenth against original list