# How would I print a message if my statistics.mode finds no mode?

Tags: python

If I wanted to add a user-friendly message that says `"No mode found"` if the `statistics.mode` does not find a mode?
The program is for analyzing statistics.
Here is the code.

```
import statistics

list = [1, 2, 3]
print(statistics.mode(list))
```

Edit: This question has been solved. Thanks for the help, everyone. I fixed it by adding:

```
if len(list)==len(set(list)):
    print('No mode found')
```

My thanks to Kevin Wang for the answer.

Comment: What is needing this error message? Are you using a tkinter GUI, a matplotlib plot, a console output?? You need to provide code and be more specific!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called "exception handling".  Python-specific docs can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#exceptions).

For your example, you could do

```
import statistics

list = [1, 2, 3]
try:
  print(statistics.mode(list))
except statistics.StatisticsError:
  print('No mode found')
```

(Alternatively, you could be pre-emptive about checking for the lack of mode: [check if all elements in a list are unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278122/checking-if-all-elements-in-a-list-are-unique).  This would amount to

```
import statistics

list = [1, 2, 3]
if len(list)==len(set(list)):
  print('No mode found')
else:
  print(statistics.mode(list))
```

)